# MySQL - Select all customers and each customer's total orders and total value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

For each customer, I want to return: id, name, total_orders, total_value

Customers:

```
╔════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║    NAME     ║
╠════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ John Smith  ║
║  2 ║ Jim Jimmers ║
╚════╩═════════════╝
```

Orders:

```
╔═══════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║  ID   ║ CUSTOMER ║ VALUE ║
╠═══════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 34656 ║        1 ║    20 ║
║ 37345 ║        2 ║    25 ║
║ 38220 ║        1 ║    15 ║
║ 39496 ║        1 ║    38 ║
║ 41752 ║        1 ║     9 ║
║ 43734 ║        2 ║    20 ║
╚═══════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

How do I select a result like:

```
╔════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║    NAME     ║ TOTALORDERS ║ TOTAL_VALUE ║
╠════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ John Smith  ║           4 ║          82 ║
║  2 ║ Jim Jimmers ║           2 ║          45 ║
╚════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        a.Name,
        COUNT(b.Customer) totalOrders,
        SUM(b.value) total_value
FROM    Customers a
        LEFT JOIN Orders b
            ON a.ID = b.Customer
GROUP   BY a.ID,
        a.Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71ae4/2)

OR

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        a.Name,
        COUNT(b.Customer) totalOrders,
        COALESCE(SUM(b.value), 0) total_value
FROM    Customers a
        LEFT JOIN Orders b
            ON a.ID = b.Customer
GROUP   BY a.ID,
        a.Name
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Result,

```
╔════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║    NAME     ║ TOTALORDERS ║ TOTAL_VALUE ║
╠════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ John Smith  ║           4 ║          82 ║
║  2 ║ Jim Jimmers ║           2 ║          45 ║
╚════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: Simple and clear. COUNT doesn't need to be COALESCEd, though.

Answer (score 0):

This query should give your deriderated output:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, count(*) AS total_orders, sum(o.value) AS total_value
FROM Customers AS c
     LEFT JOIN Orders AS o ON c.id = o.customer
GROUP BY c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a inner join and then a sum by grouping user id.

SQL join is used to merge tables by an equality point, you should give a look at this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

sorry i don't have a mysql server right now bu is something like this:

select id, name, sum(value) from (select customers.id as id, customers.name as name, orders.value as value from customers inner join orders on customers.id = orders.customer) group by id

Almost sure is not quite right but somewhere close.